# Angular validators not working when coming from other route

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have some validators in my registration form.

The registration form is in route

> /user/register

When I enter that url directly, the form works and the fields show green when validated.

But when I load the home screen and click the register link to that route, the form won't show green or validate.

Here is my code

Register form (register.component.html)

```
<ion-content color="primary">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="12">
                <ion-card color="light">
                    <ion-card-header>
                        <ion-card-title>Join the family</ion-card-title>
                    </ion-card-header>

                    <ion-card-content>
                            <form (click)="signupUser(signupForm)" [formGroup]="signupForm">
                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-label position="stacked">Screen name</ion-label>
                                    <ion-input formControlName="screenName" type="string" placeholder="Your super cool internet name" (keypress)="test()" [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls['screenName'].valid && signupForm.controls['screenName'].touched"></ion-input>
                                </ion-item>

                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
                                    <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email address" [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls['email'].valid && signupForm.controls['email'].touched">
                                    </ion-input>
                                </ion-item>

                                <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['email'].valid&& signupForm.controls['email'].touched">
                                    <ion-label>Please enter a valid email.</ion-label>
                                </ion-item>

                                <ion-item>
                                    <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
                                    <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password" [class.invalid]="!signupForm.controls['password'].valid && signupForm.controls['password'].touched">
                                    </ion-input>
                                </ion-item>
                                <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['password'].valid  && signupForm.controls['password'].touched">
                                    <ion-label>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</ion-label>
                                </ion-item>

                                <ion-button type="submit" color="" expand="block" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid">
                                    Create an Account
                                </ion-button>
                            </form>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Component code (register.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { LoadingController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss'],
})
export class RegisterComponent {

  public signupForm: FormGroup;
  public loading: any;

  constructor(
      private authService: AuthService,
      private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
      private alertCtrl: AlertController,
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      private router: Router
  ) {

    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])],
      screenName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15), Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9]+$')])],
    });

  }

  test() {
    console.log(this.signupForm.controls.email.valid);
  }

  async signupUser(signupForm: FormGroup): Promise<void> {
    if (!signupForm.valid) {
      console.log('Need to complete the form, current value: ', signupForm.value);
    } else {

      const screenName: string = signupForm.value.screenName;
      const email: string = signupForm.value.email;
      const password: string = signupForm.value.password;

      this.authService.signupUser(screenName, email, password).then(() => {
              this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
            });
          },
          error => {
            this.loading.dismiss().then(async () => {
              const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
                message: error.message,
                buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', role: 'cancel' }],
              });
              await alert.present();
            });
          }
      );
      this.loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
      await this.loading.present();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {


    //

    console.log(this.signupForm);
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The component is in a user module and has this ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'logout',
        component: LogoutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, LogoutComponent]
})

export class UserModule {

  onSubmit() {
  }

}
```

I've already tried to initialize the form in ngOnInit(), but that doesn't work.

Comment: do you get any error on the console?

Comment: Firs try to move the logic responsible for the creation of the form to ngOnInit and see if that helps. Second, can you pass you router configuration here as well?

Comment: @sagat no, we don't get any error messages.

Comment: @piotrszybicki ngOninit is the same (have tried that before). Included the route configs in the original question.

Comment: When I add a keypress event and see if the value is valid, it is. For some reason the .ion-invalid class is not removed when valid. But this only happens when I come from another page.